# How to use a javascript file on 2 pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf

Alright so I'm making PDF generator and I'm trying to make it so that when I click "Generate" button on home page it creates the PDF on other page, in another words, it should active the PDF generation code, but the problem is that I can't find a way to call the function from another page.

I tried using jQuery, but it says $ is unreferenced.

So basically this is the generation button in homepage.html:

`<form> <input style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:350px;" type="button" id="generate_pdf" value="Generate PDF">  </form`

I have

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

on both pages in head

Then I have the generation script in "script.js" file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var form = $('.form'),  
    cache_width = form.width(),  
    a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height  

    $('#generate_pdf').on('click', function () {  
        $('body').scrollTop(0);  
        generatePDF();  
    });  
    
    function generatePDF() {  
        getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {  
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),  
             doc = new jsPDF({  
                 unit: 'px',  
                 format: 'a4'  
             });  
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);  
            doc.save('Lasku.pdf');  
            form.width(cache_width);  
        });  
    }  
      
    function getCanvas() {  
        form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 55).css('max-width', 'none');  
        return html2canvas(form, {  
            imageTimeout: 2000,  
            removeContainer: true  
        });  
    }
});
```

And this is how second page looks like:

```
<form class="form">
    <img style="position: relative; right: 42px; bottom: 40px;" width="110%" height="110%" src="bg2.jpg" align=center>
```

Everything in this form gets added into the PDF file.

It works fine if I just put everything only one one page.

Please help :(

Comment: This might come down to the problem that you want to solve. You said it works fine when its on one page. So if it is working perfectly fine as is, why do you want to separate into different pages?

Comment: Because if I have it on one page, I will also see the generation of the PDF on that page which is ugly, so I want to call the function from other page so it doesn't show the process. Like you see in other websites where you put some information and it generates a PDF to another page, that's what I'm tryna do. Basically when I said "everything in this form gets added to the PDF" it also shows everything Im adding on the webpage which is kinda wack... i want it to be an invisible process.

Comment: It seems like a simple solution is wrap your HTML in a div that hides the content.

Comment: Would it hide it from the PDF as well? It's using jspdf btw, you probably noticed tho.

Comment: Looking at the code you could actually just use CSS to position the form off the screen. That way the PDF generator will still get the width and content without it showing on the screen.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for the tip. I'll test it and get back to you if it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Well regardless of what I said before, I wanted to get back to you and say it worked. It's a little unpractical to just move the form off page, but yeah it works and that's the important part. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you. In the generatepdf function, you can simply add a class to the form that adds the proper CSS positioning, then have a button that says CREATE A NEW PDF and that button removes the class from the form and resets it. Once its down, you won't even notice that it is happening.